# Trouble Setting Plot y-axis using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to chart a graph using matplotlib and am having trouble setting the y-axis -- appreciate your help!

```
plt.axes() 
plt.ylim([0, 150]) 
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 150, 10))
 
plt.plot(df_merged['Year'], df_merged['Number of Grants'], label =
'Number of Grants') plt.plot(df_merged['Year'], df_merged['Number of Priorities'], label = 'Number of Priorities')
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like maybe the values for the y-axis might be strings-- try converting them to ints/floats. [the .astype method might be useful](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

```
"11" > "105"
```

evaluates to true in Python.